# Solve the inequality $\cos 2\theta -3\sin \theta-2\geq 0$ for $0^{\circ}\le \theta \le 360^{\circ}$.

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

This question is in A-levels chapter 3 trigonometry. I have no teacher as I am doing self studying. This sub chapter I learned about all the double angle formulae but I don't know how it is related and how to solve this question. If someone could help me that would be great. I got $-2\sin^2\theta-3\sin\theta-1\geqslant 0$ so far don't know if it is correct. then got −1⩽sin⩽−1/2 how do you solve this. Please help me I have been stuck on his for 2 hours.

Comment: Hint: express $\cos 2x$ using only sines.

Comment: i took the hint and i got (cos²θ-sin²θ)-3sinθ-2>=0 the change it to (1-sin²θ-sin²θ)-3sinθ and then converted it to -3sin²θ-3sinθ-1>=0 but from here I don't know what to do

Comment: Welcome to MSE: use $$\cos 2\theta =1-2\sin^2\theta$$and solve like a quadratic

Comment: @Khosrotah Thank you i did and i got -2sin²θ-3sinθ-1>=0 from here I don't know where to go.

Comment: You have to go back to algebra and learn how to solve quadratics. $$2x^2+3x+1\leqslant 0\iff(x+1)(2x+1)\leqslant 0\iff-1\leqslant x\leqslant-1/2.$$ Now solve $-1\leqslant\sin\theta\leqslant-1/2$.

Comment: Thank you @metamorphy I put this into a calculator however this is the part I am now stuck in how do you solve −1⩽sin⩽−1/2?

Comment: @mary james You might want to read more on trigonometric inequalities here https://cnx.org/contents/qtuGRd4d@6/Trigonometric-inequalities

Comment: Thank youuu very much @junumboxi !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using a calculator do arcsin(-1) and arcsin(-1/2). Sin has a period of 360 degrees so if the calculator outputs something outside of $0\le\theta\le360$ you might need to add a multiple of 360.

Comment: YESS it worked thank you so much!

Comment: Using a calculator to solve $\sin\theta=-1$ or $-\dfrac12$??!!!

Comment: Sorry that would be 270 and 330 degrees

Comment: Oh wait is it actually between 210 and 330

Comment: @Bernard: ... and paying *so much* attention to $-1$, yeah.